# Php mysql get event from day error?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem getting all dates from a month by my code I am want to list all day in the month and then get events from my DB. Can I have a while loop in a for loop? If I have two dates in my DB now I have 3 and 4 the while loop looping the for loop two times.

Can someone show me how I can get this problem fixed I need a function? please help?

The picture below hopefully helps you to understand my problem.

my database
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dkQq.jpg)

the result i am getting that is wrong.
[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpLSp.png)

this is what i want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCde0.png)

```
 <table>
<?php
 //database connent
    include 'anslutsqli.php'; 
//sql select day from events have now two dates in my db
$sql = "SELECT day FROM test";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    //naming the sql dates var
    $sqldates = array();  
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
array_push($sqldates, $row['day']);
} 
//setting first day
  $firstday = '1';

  $two = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2018); // 31
  //for loop to get all days in month( this makes the while loop run two times i have two dates in my db 3 and 4)
  for ($number = $firstday; $number <= $two; $number++)

  if (in_array($number, $sqldates)) {
    echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#f44242'>$sqldates</td>";
  } else {
    echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#1e8e8e'>$number</td>";
  }

?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a loop inside another loop, if you are getting 3 days in the first loop (while), then you will repeat the (for) 3 times also and that is why you are get your results repeated. Suggest to remove the while, maybe place the results into array and then do the second loop outside like this

```
$sqldates = array();  
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
array_push($sqldates, $row['day']);
} 

  $firstday = '1';
  //get the cal they in selected month 
  $two = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2018); // 31
  //for loop to get all days in month( this makes the while loop run two times i have two dates in my db 3 and 4)
  for ($number = $firstday; $number <= $two; $number++)
  //if makes the nubers from database red.  
  if (in_array($number, $sqldate)) {
    echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#f44242'>$number</td>";
  } else {
    echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#1e8e8e'>$number</td>";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! works when i echo $sqldates in the first if line i get the word array as result but the backgraund color works. Can i get the $sqldates to show the day from the database? I updated my code on top.

Comment: well you can do one of two things, one is that the $number is in fact your $sqldates[x] value and so you can simply replace the $sqld by $number. another is to replace the in_array by array_search and then echo  $sqldates[array_serach($number, $sqldate)] instead. both will work and honestly i would go with the first option.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help i try it later need to get the dates by sql. I Think i can go on from here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Database which is capable of Date functions, you are recommended to use them.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `events` WHERE DAY(`day`)=24 AND MONTH(`day`)=12 AND YEAR(`day`)=2017
```

Would fetch all `id` from `events` which are on 2017-12-24.

You can even use `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` to fit it to your needs.

Comment: Not at Home now try it later. Still think the while loop make the for loop two Times the problem is in the php code. And needs a php function i Think.

Comment: And what if i have day 3 and 4 in this Month? No still Think the problem is i need a nested loop or a php function go fix this.

Comment: Then use `OR` condition. Example: ` .. AND (DAY(`day`)=3 OR (DAY(`day`)=4) ...`

Comment: SELECT `id`, `day` FROM `events` WHERE DAY(`day`)=03 AND MONTH(`day`)=12 AND YEAR(`day`)=2018 or DAY(`day`)=04 AND MONTH(`day`)=12 AND YEAR(`day`)=2018 try my code and you see it not work the while loop looping it self now i have two events in my database if i have 3 events it looping it self 3 times my picture explains it. Still is in the php code i think.

Comment: You did not set the braces.

Comment: You need to understand difference between AND and OR and the parentheses. Simplified example: `day=3 OR day=4 AND year=2018` should be written as `(day=3 OR day=4) AND year=2018` which generates 2 expressions instead of 3 because of the parentheses.

Comment: I think my question is not clear so you understand what i mean i have updated my code and added 3 mor pictures of what i am asking. Change the days to 5 6 and 7. In my picture the whlie loop it self 3 times. Thinking the problem still is in the php code. Try my code if you have the time so you see what i mean. Thanks for your help.